# comparing csv files values with mean squared error

Tags: python, mean-square-error

I have 2 csv files which one consists of exactly 1 column and 27 rows (only with numbers) and i want to compare these 2 csv files row by row taking the mean squared error and print the result of every comparison so i can calculate the average mean squared error in the end.i am using pandas and sklearn any help really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
cars = pd.read_csv('koula.csv')
moto = pd.read_csv('katerina.csv')
print(cars)
print(moto)
for i in range(cars):
    for j in range(moto):
       print(mean_squared_error(cars,moto))
```

Comment: Can you post the general structure of your dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate for just one value in each row you should do:

```
for i in range(len(cars)):
   print(mean_squared_error(cars[i],moto[i]))
```

This works if your datasets have the same length.

If you however try to calculate the error for all the rows in you datasets just use:

```
print(mean_squared_error(cars.values, moto.values))
```

This will do the same thing as above but it takes the mean of all values and this will be more useful.

Lastly if they are the instances `pd.Series` class you do not have to use `.values`

Comment: `cars` is a pandas dataframe. One way to iterate over the rows would be `range(cars.shape[0])` instead of `range(cars)` which would throw an exception.

Comment: Sir thank you very much it was exactly what i was looking for! But i have one last question when i am using your first suggestion why it returns me an erro like this:  for i in range(cars):
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.?

Comment: Pardon me I edited now. For that you can use the above comment or just add `len(cars)` to your code